# how to add a string to string list

Tags: f#

```
    let IntAndString value = 
        let (|Match|_|) pattern input =
            let m = Regex.Match(input, pattern) in
            if m.Success then Some ([ for g in m.Groups -> g.Value ]) else None
        match value with
            | Match "(\d+)(\w+)" x -> x
            | Match "(\w+)" x -> x
            | Match "(\d+)" x -> x + "MY VALUE"
            | _ -> List.Empty
```

how can I add a string to my string list here ?

Comment: `(\w+)` also matches digits, so your third case will never match. You should swap the second and third cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append to a list with the `@` operator. This operator concatenates two lists together, so you'll have to wrap the element you want to append in its own list like this:

```
| Match "(\d+)" x -> x @ ["MY VALUE"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the list constructor, `::`.  If prepending instead of appending is OK:

```
| Match "(d\+)" x -> "MY VALUE" :: x
```